# how to update rails 2.3.5 to rails 3.0.1 in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

recently i installed rails 2.3.5 using apt-get. After installing rails 3.0.1 the version shows on as rails 2.3.5 when i type rails -v command. How to change that? or can i update rails 2.3.5 to 3.0.1? pls help me out

Answer (score 3):

You should NOT use apt to manage your rubies or your gems! (NEVER)

Use RVM to manage your Rubies and your gems : http://rvm.io/

Answer (score 1):

Try `gem uninstall rails` then select version of rails gem which you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the upgrade directions given at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html

Answer (score 1):

to install Rails 3 use this script..

```
sudo gem install rails --pre
```

It's possible to control version of Rails

```
rails _2.3.8_ --version
rails _3.0.0.rc_ --version
```

Hope it'll work. For more details https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Installing_rails it's a best url

Oh, I got another solution. Try this script, it'll work

```
sudo gem install -v=3.0.1 rails --include-dependencies
```